# PostgreSQL - Fastest way to get duplicates

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates

Need to quickly find duplicates in a table by a given field name.

I have the query below but it runs still for 1.5 minutes even after i did put index on the table field.

```
select * from (
  SELECT *,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY b.name) AS rowCount
  FROM table b
) a
where a.rowCount > 1
```

Comment: which field did you put the index on? what is the output for `explain analyze`?

Comment: Desired results would really help.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
select name, count(*)
from table 
group by name
having count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: this gives duplicate id's, not duplicate names.  Assuming `id` is the primary key, this will in fact give zero results

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select name, min(id), count(id)
from table
group by name
where count(id) > 1
```

and this will be a lot faster if you have the name column indexed.

Comment: why do you need min(id)?

Comment: @NiVeR - to have the id of at least one of the two (or more) people whose names are identical.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly get the duplicate names without any extra columns apart from `name` in the select clause.

```
select name
from table
group by name
having count(*)>1
```